# Place form1(No border style) inside of form2(Normal border style)

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to know if it is possible to show/place a form1 INSIDE form2.
So that form1 is stuck inside form2.

Any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The word you're looking for is [MDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_document_interface) or Multiple Document Interface.

Just set form2's `IsMdiContainer` property to `true` 
and set form1's `MdiParent` property to be form2 like so:

```
form2.IsMdiContainer = true;
form1.MdiParent = form2;
```

Of course, you cause the visual designer to write the first line for you by setting the property in the properties section:

[image]

**EDIT**

Here's an easy example.
Say you have 2 forms. `FormContainer` and `FormChild`.
`FormContainer` is the application's main form.

All you need to do is make sure that `FormContainer`'s `IsMdiContainer` property is set to `true` and then you could add instances of other forms to this one by setting those instances' `MdiParent` property. Except for the main form, any instance of the `Form` class or a subclass is by default **not visible**.

```
public partial class FormContainer : Form {

    public FormContainer() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.IsMdiContainer = true;
        // if you're not excited about the new form's backcolor
        // just change it back to the original one like so
        // note: The dark gray color which is shown on the container form
        //       is not it's actual color but rather a misterious' control's color.
        //       When you turn a plain ol' form into an MDIContainer
        //       you're actually adding an MDIClient on top of it

        var theMdiClient = this.Controls
            .OfType<Control>()
            .Where(x => x is MdiClient)
            .First();
        theMdiClient.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
    }

    private void FormContainer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var child = new FormChild();
        child.MdiParent = this;
        child.Show();

        // if you wish to specify the position, size, Anchor or Dock styles
        // of the newly created child form you can, like you would normally do
        // for any control
        child.Location = new Point(50, 50);
        child.Size = new Size(100, 100);
        child.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right;
    }

}
```

Comment: I wrote Form2 f2 = new Form2(this); f2.IsMdiContainer = true; this.MdiParent = f2; in the form1_load block. But when i start the program it closes again. What should i do? Form1 is the startup form.

Comment: It doesn't matter where i write the code, the program still just closes.

Comment: Sorry i flipped the forms over. now it doesn't close. but i can't see the things from the second form.

Comment: Well.. you mixed them up a bit. Check out the **edit**.

Comment: Ok.. that's because you have to call the `Show` method of the child form just after you've assigned its `MdiParent` property.

Comment: It works Thanks alot. One last question: the background turns into a diffrent color, how do i avoid that?

Comment: AH... Sorry, my bad :D

Comment: No actually it's mine. Had forgotten about this. I will delete my previous comment. Check the latest edit again.

Comment: It doesn't change the color. Any idea why? Can i do it with a panel instead?

Comment: Yes.. As I said in the previous comment. It was actually me who hurried. Check out the latest edit.

Comment: Now it works. But can i programatically change the position of the childform?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37539/discussion-between-eduard-dumitru-and-masterxd)

Comment: No need, I found out what I needed. Thank you very much for your help.